# Is there a way to do an Ajax Post to an ASPX page that doesn't call a static function?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

The question says it all.  I am having no trouble making Ajax calls into my ASPX page - as long as I use static methods.  However, I'd like to store a result in the session and so need a "live" function call.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done quite a bit of research on this problem and, while @latr0dectus' answer may work, I am looking to implement quite a few calls back to the application from within the page.  Perhaps I needed to do more research but I did not find a way to call multiple methods within the Generic Http handler nor a way to pass in complex arguments.  So, this didn't work very well for me.

A much easier solution is just to use a a WebService and to use the [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)] attribute.

A complete example of a Session-aware web service that you can reach from Ajax is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.SessionState;

[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class SCMasterService : System.Web.Services.WebService {

    public SCMasterService () {
    }

    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public string GetSummaryList(string ID)
    {
        return Session["SomeVal"];
    }
}
```

To call this from a Javascript/JQuery/Ajax "Post" you will need two key lines:

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
```

Makes this web service available to Ajax and

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
```

enables session management in the called method.

Answer (score 1):

Post to a Generic Http handler (.ashx) and have it inherit from IRequireSession interface.  Then you can save to session.